# Adding Javascript Counter to my Images

Tags: javascript, counter, instafeedjs

I'm trying to add a JavaScript counter to the images I'm pulling in through an instagram API. The hope is by adding a counter I can give the images a unique ID, allowing me to manipulate them into a slider. I've just started learning about counters and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the page I'm working on with the images: http://carabinercoffee.com/instagram.html

Below is the code I'm using with the instafeed.js plugin. I think there might be a way to use the template section to work in something but that's just a guess.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
       get: 'user',
       userId: xxxxxxx,
       accessToken: 'xxxxxxxxx',
       limit: 24,
       resolution: 'low_resolution',
       template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}"/></a>',
       useHttp: true ,

  });

  userFeed.run();
</script>
```

Comment: Does userFeed.run() return an array of images?

Comment: @mwilson It returns a list of 24 images, all inside of <a> tags. I'm not quite sure if they're an array. Check out the website I linked (caracbinercoffee.com/instagram.html) to see the code in action

Comment: So you just want to add an `id` attribute to each of your pictures?

Comment: yes! That's what I'm looking to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to issue each `a` tag an id, you can use the following code:

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
    aTags[i].setAttribute("id", i);
}
```

This code will cycle through all `a` tags in your current page and issue an incremental id.

Before:

```
  <a href="google.com">Test</a>
  <a href="google.com">Test</a>
  <a href="google.com">Test</a>
  <a href="google.com">Test</a>
  <a href="google.com">Test</a>
```

After:

```
  <a id="0" href="google.com">Test</a>
  <a id="1" href="google.com">Test</a>
  <a id="2" href="google.com">Test</a>
  <a id="3" href="google.com">Test</a>
  <a id="4" href="google.com">Test</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code mwilson! I have the code working but it's not applying to the <a> tags that are generated from the API. I tried putting the code before, after and inside of the code I'm using with no luck. I've updated www.carabinercoffee.com/instagram.html with your code if you wanted to take a look.

Comment: It is working. Open up the DOM Explorer (hit f12) and you'll see that they have ID's

Comment: I see what you're saying. Try changing out the 'a' reference in the code to 'img'

Comment: Disregard all of that, actually. You need to make sure that the script block I gave you runs after your API is finished.

Comment: hmmmm I changed 'a' to 'img' and it's still the same result. I updated the code on carabinercoffee.com/instagram.html for reference.

Comment: *Update* I started messing with the template code and added a class="test1" line. Now all the img's have the class 'test1'. Any idea how I could apply this with your code or a way of giving them all a unique class or id?

code: template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" class="test1"/></a>',

Comment: I'm not sure of what all you have setup, but basically what is happening is that the code block I gave you is running before your API call is finished. You'll need to figure out a way to make sure that code block runs after your API call has finished. Try putting the code block inside of `$(document).ready()` or some other load event to test.

Comment: I added a $(document).ready() and put both parts of the code in there and it's still not working. Updated carabinercofee.com/instagram.html for reference. This is a weird one. Thanks for all your help so far mwilson!

Comment: Is there a way to assign letters instead of numbers with your code? I'm coming across some issues with calling an ID that starts with a number.

Answer (score -1):

mwilson's answer along with a small add into the instafeeed code worked out this problem. I needed to add an **after function** into the plugin's code for mwilson's solution to take effect. here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
   get: 'user',
    userId: xxxxxxx,
    accessToken: 'xxxxxxx',
    limit: 24,
    resolution: 'low_resolution',
    template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" id="{{id}}"/></a>',
    useHttp: true,

    after: function () {

    var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
    [i].setAttribute("id", i);}
    },
});
userFeed.run();
});

</script>
```